# osmdroid displaying map from .mbtiles

Tags: android, osmdroid, mbtiles

I have a problem trying to display map from .mbtiles file using osmdroid 5.6.5

this is my code:

```
val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath.plus("/osmdroid/tiles/map.mbtiles")
        val file = File(path)

        val tilesSource = XYTileSource(file.absolutePath, 1, 14, 256, "jpg", arrayOf<String>())

        val register = SimpleRegisterReceiver(this)

        val offProvider = OfflineTileProvider(register, arrayOf(file))



    mapView?.apply {
            setTileSource(tilesSource)
            tileProvider = offProvider
...
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: permissions? did you check if the file exists?

Comment: Permissions are rights checked, debugging i can see the path is correct and the file exist.